# Identifying URL bar element in Firefox

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

What is the **"tag name"** (or other way to identify the element) for the URL field in Firefox?

e.g. when you want to open a new tab in Firefox, you can select the `body` by:

```
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
```

and, for example, open a new tab:

```
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```

Is there a simple "tag name" that anyone knows of for the URL bar?

Normally, you can right click on elements in Firefox and press `Q` to identify them, but in this case, that doesn't apply.

---

**EDIT:** I am not trying to find the URL bar element so that I can navigate to a new web page. I'd like to find it so I can send the "return" key to it as a workaround to refresh the page.

Comment: you can't use driver.navigate().refresh(); ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's 'urlbar'. At least that's how you call it when you code autocomplete features...

Answer (score 0):

The URL bar that you see in the browser is **not a part of the page**.

If you want to get the current url, use [`.current_url`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.current_url):

```
driver.current_url
```

If you want to change the url, use [`.get()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get):

```
driver.get("new_url_here")
```

You can also navigate through the browsing history using [`back()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.back) and [`forward()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.forward).

FYI, [Navigating](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html) documentation page has a lot of relevant information.